# Table : Overfull hbox

Tags: tables

When I compile the following code, I get the error overfull hbox and I cannot see the right end of the table. Does anyone know how to fix it ?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccc}
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Tolérances d'ajustement}} \\
 \hline
Alésage & Arbre &Appariement & Raisons\\
 \hline
Manivelle&Axe&&\\
Roulements&Axes& M7 - js5&Charges faibles et variables, petit diamètrem bague exterieure ne coulisse pas, logement en une pièce\\
Cloches&Roulements&H7 - p6&Transmission de petits couples sans sécurité supplémentaire\\
Bielle&Coussinet&H7 - p6&\\
Coussinet&Axes bielle &IT7 - f7&\\
Palier & Tourillon&H7-p6&\\
Palier&Maneton&H7 - p6&\\
Plateau&pales & H8 - h7& Jeu pour colle\\
Pied helice&Fixation helice&H7 - js6& incertain\\
Opercule& Axe bielle& H7 - k6&  incertain  \\
Palier & Goupille &M6 - m6& serrage leger\\
Engrenages&Axes&H7 - p6&\\

 \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 5):

Material in a column of type `c` does not get line-broken automatically. Thus, even though you've set `\textwidth` as the first argument of the `tabular*` environment, there's no guarantee that the combined width of the four columns won't, in fact, exceed `\textwidth`. That's what's happening in your code.

Instead of using a `tabular*` environment, I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment, with an overall width of `\textwidth` and with a modified form of the `X` column type for the final column. The specific modification used in the code below typesets the column material ragged-right while still permitting hyphenation.

Some additional suggestions:

- Use the macros of the `booktabs` package -- specifically, `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` -- instead of the basic `\hline` instruction.
- Use `l` instead of `c` as the column type for the first three columns.
- Load the `caption` package and apply some extra mark-up to distinguish more clearly what the logical parts of the table are (caption vs. body).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % modified 'X' column type
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\captionsetup{font=bf,skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\caption*{Tolérances d'ajustement}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lllL@{}}
\toprule
Alésage & Arbre &Appariement & Raisons\\
\midrule
Manivelle&Axe&&\\
Roulements&Axes& M7 - js5&Charges faibles et variables, petit diamètrem bague extérieure ne coulisse pas, logement en une pièce\\
Cloches&Roulements&H7 - p6&Transmission de petits couples sans sécurité supplémentaire\\
Bielle&Coussinet&H7 - p6&\\
Coussinet&Axes bielle &IT7 - f7&\\
Palier & Tourillon&H7 - p6&\\
Palier&Maneton&H7 - p6&\\
Plateau&pales & H8 - h7& Jeu pour colle\\
Pied helice&Fixation helice&H7 - js6& incertain\\
Opercule& Axe bielle& H7 - k6&  incertain  \\
Palier & Goupille &M6 - m6& serrage léger\\
Engrenages&Axes&H7 - p6&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very close to @Mico's solution. I kept the centred first three columns if you like themm,  added some vertical padding between row with `\extrarowheight` , to differentiate rows from lines in multiline cells, and corrected some typos/missing accents:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e, array, tabularx, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

    \begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccc X}
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Tolérances d'ajustement}} \\[1ex]
 \toprule
Alésage & Arbre &Appariement & Raisons \\
 \midrule
Manivelle & Axe & & \\
Roulements & Axes & M7-js5 & Charges faibles et variables, petit diamètre bague extérieure ne coulisse pas, logement en une pièce \\
Cloches & Roulements & H7-p6 & Transmission de petits couples sans sécurité supplémentaire\\
Bielle & Coussinet & H7-p6 & \\
Coussinet & Axes bielle & IT7-f7 & \\
Palier & Tourillon & H7-p6 & \\
Palier & Maneton & H7-p6 & \\
Plateau & Pales & H8-h7 & Jeu pour colle \\
Pied hélice & Fixation hélice & H7-js6 & incertain \\
Opercule & Axe bielle & H7-k6 & incertain \\
Palier & Goupille & M6-m6 & serrage léger \\
Engrenages & Axes & H7-p6\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Latex does not automatically line break in tables. As your last column contains very long text elements, the resulting table is very wide. However you can force line breaks by using a column of a fixed width, e.g. `p{4.2cm}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccp{4.2cm}}
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Tolérances d'ajustement}} \\
        \hline
        Alésage & Arbre &Appariement & Raisons\\
        \hline
        Manivelle&Axe&&\\
        Roulements&Axes& M7 - js5&Charges faibles et variables, petit diamètrem bague exterieure ne coulisse pas, logement en une pièce\\
        Cloches&Roulements&H7 - p6&Transmission de petits couples sans sécurité supplémentaire\\
        Bielle&Coussinet&H7 - p6&\\
        Coussinet&Axes bielle &IT7 - f7&\\
        Palier & Tourillon&H7-p6&\\
        Palier&Maneton&H7 - p6&\\
        Plateau&pales & H8 - h7& Jeu pour colle\\
        Pied helice&Fixation helice&H7 - js6& incertain\\
        Opercule& Axe bielle& H7 - k6&  incertain  \\
        Palier & Goupille &M6 - m6& serrage leger\\
        Engrenages&Axes&H7 - p6&\\

        \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]